# How to convert WebClient to HttpClient C# WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I need to convert the webclient code which is obsolte to httpclient.

```
using WebClient Client = new();
Client.Headers["User-Agent"] = CompanyName + "/" + ProductName;
byte[] responseBytes = Client.UploadFile("http://blahblah.com/upload.php", fileimage);
string response = Encoding.Default.GetString(responseBytes);
_ = MessageBox.Show(response, Text);
```

I need the exact same way to do this. I have seen other answers but none meet my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- `read AllByte` of file into upfilebytes array

2-create new `HttpClient` and `MultipartFormDataContent`

3- ad`d byte array to content`

4-`upload MultipartFormDataContent` content async and `store response` in response.

```
var upfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes("fileimage");

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", CompanyName + "/" + ProductName);
MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
ByteArrayContent baContent = new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes);

content.Add(baContent, "File", "filename.png");

 var response = await client.PostAsync("http://blahblah.com/upload.php", content);

 var responsestr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

MessageBox.Show(response, responsestr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way you can upload a file is something like here.However,

it's better to use HttpClientFactory to generate httpclient instance.

```
var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new("http://blahblah.com/upload.php")
};
 
await using var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("filePathHere");
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "file");
request.Headers.Add("User-Agent",CompanyName + "/" + ProductName);
using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    { new StreamContent(stream), "file", "fileNameHere" }
};

request.Content = content;

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
MessageBox.Show(response, Text);
```